# Change UIPopoverView size with navigation controller

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller, segue

i have implemented a `UIPopover` view for ipad with `navigation controller` inside. initially popover view's size is small and becomes bigger as i push to another view.

But when i press back button, only width reduce back to small but height remains the same. I have set view size explicitly from starboard and popover is by segue. can you pls help me!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the View Controller, implement `-(CGSize) contentSizeForViewInPopover`, and return a CGRect of the desired size. This is what get's used at runtime to determine the size. The storyboard setting is just an archived initialization value. [Documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW65) also mentions a few edge cases you may need to consider (there is actually a chain of responsibility when presenting view controllers and things can start to feel complex, but it's not that bad)

Comment: can u pls tell me in which view controller should i implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing UINavigationController and overriding its contentSizeForViewInPopover. This works for me :)

It seems that by default UINavigationController looks only at width of it's child view controllers. (or perhaps only grows in height?)